# How to print the newest inserted data in one event?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, session

I'd like to print a freshly inputted data. So, after a user fills out a form the data that user input is **saved** and printed **after** it's succesfully saved. This is my code:

```
//this is submit button
$('#btn_print').on('click', function(){ 
    alert("Data successfully saved");
    window.open("<?php echo site_url('con_product/print_product'); ?>","_blank"); //open new window to print
});
```

This is the form:

```
<form id="f_product" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('con_vendor/ins_pengajuan'); ?>">
...
</form>
```

So, here are the sequence:

- User fills out form
- User click submit
- Form data is send to controller and open new page to print
- Data is saved and set a session
- Use the session as a key to retrieve data
- Show data in a new page.

The problem is the code open new page to print first, then saved data, then set session. I've tried to move the `window.open("<?php echo site_url('con_product/print_product'); ?>","_blank");` to the controller but it's failed.

So, my question is how to saved the data first, then set session, then print data?

Comment: You can't open a new window with PHP inside it, PHP is server-side, not client-side.

Comment: well, I'm open to any solution possible :)

Comment: Make a new file with your code in it, and then open the window to that url.

Comment: So put the print button in the page that gets output after the form is submitted. Seems fairly obvious unless you want to submit form using ajax

Comment: @charlietfl I'd like to simplify everything. So user only click button and get the print out. Not get redirected to a page of data list and click it one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX for this rather than for submit:-

```
$('#btn_print').on('click', function(){ 
    /* 
      make ajax to con_vendor/ins_pengajuan
      an on success do
    */
    window.open("<?php echo site_url('con_product/print_product'); ?>","_blank"); 
});
```